# ng-grid export to CSV plugin -- how to download all data even if paged

Tags: javascript, angularjs, csv, angularjs-directive, ng-grid

Hi I am working with angular's ng-grid to display about 1000 rows of data. Users are allowed to view the data in the actual table 10, 20, or 100 rows at a time..but regardless of how much data they are viewing at a time, I want them to be able to download a CSV of all 1000 rows.

Is there a way to do this with the current plugin? I've been struggling for a while now since the plug in always goes to the actual ng-grid for the data to create a CSV from.

ng-grid plug in:

```
ngGridCsvExportPlugin = function(opts) {
var self = this;
self.grid = null;
self.scope = null;
self.init = function(scope, grid, services) {
    self.grid = grid;
    self.scope = scope;

    function showDs() {
        var keys = [];

        for (var f in grid.config.columnDefs) { if (grid.config.columnDefs[f].field) { keys.push(grid.config.columnDefs[f].field); }}
        var csvData = '';
        function csvStringify(str) {
            if (str == null) return '';  // we want to catch anything null-ish, hence just == not ===
            if (typeof(str) === 'number') return '' + str;
            if (typeof(str) === 'boolean') return (str ? 'TRUE' : 'FALSE') ;
            if (typeof(str) === 'string') return str.replace(/"/g,'""');
            return JSON.stringify(str).replace(/"/g,'""');
        }
        function swapLastCommaForNewline(str) {
            var newStr = str.substr(0,str.length - 1);
            return newStr + "\n";
        }
        for (var k in keys) {
            csvData += '"' + csvStringify(keys[k]) + '",';
        }
        csvData = swapLastCommaForNewline(csvData);
        var gridData = grid.data;
        for (var gridRow in gridData) {
            for ( k in keys) {
                var curCellRaw;
                if (opts != null && opts.columnOverrides != null && opts.columnOverrides[keys[k]] != null) {
                  curCellRaw = opts.columnOverrides[keys[k]](gridData[gridRow][keys[k]]);
                } else {
                  curCellRaw = gridData[gridRow][keys[k]];
                }
                csvData += '"' + csvStringify(curCellRaw) + '",';
            }
            csvData = swapLastCommaForNewline(csvData);
        }
        var fp = grid.$root.find(".ngFooterPanel");
        var csvDataLinkPrevious = grid.$root.find('.ngFooterPanel .csv-data-link-span');
        if (csvDataLinkPrevious != null) {csvDataLinkPrevious.remove() ; }
        var link = "data:text/csv;charset=UTF-8," + encodeURIComponent(csvData);
        var csvDataLinkHtml = "<span class=\"csv-data-link-span\">";
        csvDataLinkHtml += "<br><a class=\"btn hidden btn-primary exportTable2CSV\" href=" + link + " download=\"Export.csv\">CSV Export</a></br></span>" ;
        fp.append(csvDataLinkHtml);
        scope.$emit("exportTable2CSVLinkReady", link);
    }

    setTimeout(showDs, 0);
    scope.catHashKeys = function() {

        showDs();

      hash = '';
      for (idx in scope.renderedRows) { hash += scope.renderedRows[idx].$$hashKey;  }
      return hash;
    };
    scope.$watch('catHashKeys()', showDs);
};
};
```

Comment: Without ever having used ng-grid, is there a way for you to have a secret option for all 1000 to be viewed, exported, and then back to whatever view they were using before?

Comment: unfortunately there isn't

Comment: hmm. that does make that a bit more complicated. do you have a fiddle set up by chance??

Comment: I have not set up a fiddle...but the idea is very simple. I have my grid showing paged data...but I want the csv plugin to work on all of the data. I've managed to get all the data in the actual plugin funtion, but then its undefined within self.init (pasted code above) because of the asynchronous nature of the plugin :(

Answer (score 0):

You have all the data, maybe you can use [ng-csv](https://github.com/asafdav/ng-csv) to export csv file.

Here is example. [sfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/asafdav/dR6Nb/)

html:

```
<h2>Export {{sample}}</h2>
  <div>
      <button type="button" ng-csv="getArray" filename="test.csv">Export</button>
</div>
```

javascript :

```
angular.module('csv', ['ngCsv']);

function Main($scope) {
    $scope.sample = "Sample";
    $scope.getArray = [{a: 1, b:2}, {a:3, b:4}];                            
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. As per your explanation it is not clear what is undefined...
   have you tried accessing data through scope not grid?
2. As you might have observed that there is no such hook/function which will export all data at once, so i suggest to make user change page selection to display all records only after that enable CSV export option?